# How to calculate running total based on year in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to calculate running value in sql server 2012 version.
Here is my sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE #RollingTotalsExample
(
    [Date]     DATE PRIMARY KEY
    ,[Value]   INT
);

INSERT INTO #RollingTotalsExample
SELECT '2011-01-01',626
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-02-01',231 UNION ALL SELECT '2011-03-01',572
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-04-01',775
UNION ALL SELECT '2011-12-01',361 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-01',461
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-02-01',928 UNION ALL SELECT '2012-03-01',855
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-04-01',605  
UNION ALL SELECT '2012-12-01',26;

SELECT * FROM #RollingTotalsExample;
```

Expected output:

```
Date    Value   Runing Value
1/01/2011   626 626
1/02/2011   231 857
1/03/2011   572 1429
1/04/2011   775 2204
1/12/2011   361 2565
1/01/2012   461 461
1/02/2012   928 1389
1/03/2012   855 2244
1/04/2012   605 2849
1/12/2012   26  2875
```

Running value should be calculated for year based.

Comment: You could use a cross apply if you wanted. `select * from #rollingtotalsexample t cross apply (select sum(value) from #rollingtotalsexample where date <= t.date and year(date) = year(t.date)) r(runningvalue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions. Partition by `Year(Date)` will restart your running sum when year changes and order by `date` will ensure that sum will be calculated with date.

```
SELECT Date, Value, 
SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DATE) ORDER BY DATE) AS RunningValue
FROM #RollingTotalsExample
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this

```
SELECT A.DATE, A.VALUE, (SELECT SUM(B.VALUE)
                       FROM #ROLLINGTOTALSEXAMPLE B
                       WHERE B.DATE <= A.DATE) AS RUNING_TOTAL
FROM   #ROLLINGTOTALSEXAMPLE A
ORDER BY A.DATE;
```